# Migrating plugins from Rails 2 to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, autocomplete, upgrade, captcha

I have a few **plugins** in my **Rails 2** app, such as **Recaptcha** or **Auto_complete**. After I have successfully **migrated** everything else, is there a **quick way to migrate all of the plugins**?

My first thought is to delete all of them, and **reinstall** because the last time I touched Rails 2.3.2 it used **Protytype** and not **jQuery**.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. Deleted 'em all, and worked with Gemfile - added the gems into it, like recaptcha, and autocomplete. So many things were changed, for example, Jquery replaced the Prototype etc. But after some minor but numerous fixes, it all seems to work fine.